# How to assign the same value to multiple members in a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, assignment-operator

I was wondering if there was a more concise way to assign the same variable to multiple members of the same struct?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
```

It just seems like a lot of repitition. I don't want to alter the struct in any way I just wondered if there is any way I can make the above code more neat? But here is the code for the struct anyway.

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

TIA

Comment: If you want to assign all fields of the structure you can assign a whole structure instead of individual fields. Or you can create a function or a preprocessor macro.

Comment: I'm not sure it's neater (and won't be faster due to the packed attribute), but you could use a *compound literal*: `image[i][j] = (RGBTRIPLE){average, average, average};`.

Comment: another possibility, you could `image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;`

Comment: Further to my previous use of *compound literal*, note that the initializers are in the same order as the struct, i.e. BGR. You could use a macro to construct a compound literal in RGB order if more convenient: `#define MK_RGB(r, g, b) ((RGBTRIPLE){.rgbtBlue = (b), .rgbtGreen = (g), .rgbtRed = (r)})`, then `image[i][j] = MK_RGB(someR, someG, someB);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be

```
image[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
```

If you're getting tired of typing "`image[i][j]`", and you're doing a lot with it in the same stretch of code, you could set up a temporary variable:

```
RGBTRIPLE *trip = &image[i][j];

trip->rgbtBlue = trip->rgbtGreen = trip->rgbtRed = average;
```

Setting up a temporary variable like this has some pros and cons:

- Pro: it saves typing
- Con: but saving typing isn't really a goal, you only type it once
- Pro: it can be easier to read
- Con: if you're not careful (if `i` or `j` changes when you don't expect), it can introduce bugs

Comment: Thank you! I found your first solution the best fit for my needs. Im fairly new to programming so didn't want a massively complicated solution and this is the only time I need this in my code so that works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a read-only struct containing the default initialization values:

```
const RGBTRIPLE RGB_default = 
{ 
  .rgbtBlue  = average, 
  .rgbtGreen = average,
  .rgbtRed   = average,
};
```

And then:

```
RGBTRIPLE something[n];
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  something[i] = RGB_default;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not the solution I ended up going with this time as I didn't really want to be messing around with Structs, but certainly something I might consider another time

Answer (score 1):

(Since everyone is supplying different solutions, I'll mention mine too!)

One option is to use a *compound literal* to hold a temporary `RGBTRIPLE` filled with the desired values. Since it seems convenient to specify the values in RGB order to match the name of the type, some handy macros can be defined to construct the compound literal:

```
#define MK_RGB(r, g, b) ((RGBTRIPLE){ .rgbtBlue = (b), .rgbtGreen = (g), .rgbtRed = (r) })
#define MK_GREY(g) MK_RGB(g, g, g)
```

Then the original lines of code:

```
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
```

Can be changed to:

```
                image[i][j] = MK_RGB(average, average, average);
```

or:

```
                image[i][j] = MK_GREY(average);
```

Note: Compound literals were added in C11. To conform to older C standards, `MK_RGB` could be changed to a function that returns an `RGBTRIPLE`:

```
RGBTRIPLE MK_RGB(BYTE r, BYTE g, BYTE b)
{
    RGBTRIPLE rgb;
    rgb.rgbtRed = r;
    rgb.rgbtGreen = g;
    rgb.rgbtBlue = b;
    return rgb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So many different options! I'm fairly new to programming and not really sure what a compound literal is (im sure its not that complicated and i'll come across it soon) but for this problem i settled for a slightly less elegant but simpler option.

Answer (score 0):

2 easy ways I can think of off the top of my head:

1. Use a function:

ie.

```
void RGBstructSet(RGBTRIPLE *lStruct,uint8_t value){
lStruct->rgbtBlue = value;
lStruct->rgbtGreen = value;
lStruct->rgbtRed = value;
}
```

And your above 3 lines would then be replaced by:

```
structSet(&image[i][j], average);
```

2. use memset which is only guaranteed to work since your struct is "PACKED" ie.

   ```
    memset(&image[i][j],average,3)
   ```

1 has the benefit of working regardless of your struct being packed or not, 2 is slightly easier for you to do, and is more clear what is going on

Comment: Thanks. I did consider using a function at one point but seeing as this is the only time i'll be using this code it seemed like I was creating more lines of code just for the sake of it. But if I had something that needed this solution across multiple parts of code then yeah a function makes more sense.